Azure service bus: how to get topics
I'm totally new with Azure Service Bus, and just for studing I'm trying to get topics. If I'm not wrong I should use class ServiceBusAdministrationClient but when I tried to achieve my goal I got the error "InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature".
I'm using the easiest constructor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-administration-servicebusadministrationclient-ctor(system-string) ) passing the same connectionString that allows me to send and receive messages using ServiceBusClient.
Theorically I should be able to do that using the same connection string, I think that because the Service Bus Explorer developed by Paolo Salvatori (https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) is able to do that with the same connection string. Am I wrong or do I need a different connection string?
Here the code I have (copied from another post):
var administrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(ConnectionString);
AsyncPageable<TopicProperties> allTopics = administrationClient.GetTopicsAsync();
await foreach (TopicProperties topic in allTopics)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"IterateTopicsWithAwaitForeachAsync: {topic.Name}");
}

Can anyone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?
ps. I'm using .net 8

Is there a chance your connection string is invalid? The code looks fine.

I would say no, I can send and receive messages using the same one

connection string has this format: "Endpoint=sb://.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=;SharedAccessKey="

Thanks @Sean Feldman and I do agree that there might be a chance of Traffic being blocked otherwise if you give correct connection string, it will work and I have taken connection string from below:

The topics i have are:

With Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration package(ServiceBusAdministrationClient) :
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;

string ri_cs = "Endpoint=sb://rithtest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=6YXOZY=";
var ri_cl = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(ri_cs);
var ri_tp = ri_cl.GetTopicsAsync();
await foreach (var ri in ri_tp)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, Topic Name: {ri.Name}");
}

Output:

Alterantively you can use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management package(ManagementClient) :
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;

string ri_cs = "Endpoint=sb://rithtest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=6YXOhY=";
var ri_cl = new ManagementClient(ri_cs);
var rith = await ri_cl.GetTopicsAsync();
foreach (var ri in rith)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ri.Path);
}

Output:


thank you both rithwikbojja @Sean Feldman, I'm waiting for an answer from devops. By now I can close this post


var administrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(ConnectionString);
AsyncPageable<TopicProperties> allTopics = administrationClient.GetTopicsAsync();
await foreach (TopicProperties topic in allTopics)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"IterateTopicsWithAwaitForeachAsync: {topic.Name}");
}


This code is working fine. I'd double-check your connection string. Also, it is worth noting that the administrative client works via HTTP while the data client works via AMQP by default. So, there might be a chance that your data operations are working while management operations fail if HTTP traffic is blocked.

thank you. it makes sense, but there should be a way to get the topics using the connection string I have since Service Bus Explorer is able to do that. I'll try to inspect its code.

Note that SBE is using the old SDK. I don't know what that one is doing for administrative client. But trying your code from an environment where HTTP traffic is not blocked will help with the validation.
